# Is It possible to use Passport.js without Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an app which uses nodejs but I don't serve my pages via ExpressJS. It is a simple http nodejs app which I will migrate to nodejs at some stage.

However, I am playing around with Passportjs and currently I am getting 'passport.intitalize() middleware not in use' errors which from the documentation mention 'connect' and 'Express' usage.

Can I use passportjs without Expressjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version:  No, express is required for regular passport usage.

Long version: You could technically use a large portion of passport's code in a non-express application, but that could create all sorts of edge cases you *don't* want in your auth code.  It'd also probably be easier just to convert your application to express.

Answer (score 11):

Passport Strategies expect inputs on certain channels (e.g. 'Local' looks for `username` and `password` fields on `<OBJ>.body`), but if you provide for these Strategy requirements directly you **can** use Passport just fine without Express/Connect.

Take a look directly at comments lifted from the relevant Passport code:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/authenticator.js#L146

```
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
  if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
  res.end('Authenticated!');
})(req, res);
```

If you provide `req` and `res` as your own objects (paying attention to the requirements of the Strategy you're using and whatever you're using of [req/res in authenticate](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js)), you have total control.

(Or just write a simple [custom framework wrapper](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/framework/connect.js)).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like hapi is an option:

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/authenticator.js#L97
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-passport

Answer (score 0):

take an example for oauth2 without express, besides papercowboy's local example:

```
const i_url = require('url');
const i_crypto = require('crypto');
const i_jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
const i_passport = require('passport');
const i_OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;

const AUTH_SSO_AUTH_URL = process.env.SSO_AUTH_URL;
const AUTH_SSO_TOKEN_URL = process.env.SSO_TOKEN_URL;
const AUTH_SSO_CLIENT_ID = process.env.SSO_CLIENT_ID;
const AUTH_SSO_SECRET = process.env.SSO_SECRET;
const AUTH_SSO_CB_URL = process.env.SSO_CB_URL;


i_passport.use(new i_OAuth2Strategy({
   authorizationURL: AUTH_SSO_AUTH_URL,
   tokenURL: AUTH_SSO_TOKEN_URL,
   clientID: AUTH_SSO_CLIENT_ID,
   clientSecret: AUTH_SSO_SECRET,
   callbackURL: AUTH_SSO_CB_URL,
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cbFn) => {
   if (!params.id_token) return cbFn(new Error('invalid user'), null);
   const tokenObj = i_jwtDecode(params.id_token);
   if (!tokenObj.sub) return cbFn(new Error('invalid user name'), null);
   const username = tokenObj.sub.split('@')[0];
   const userObj = { username, refreshToken };
   return cbFn(null, userObj);
}));
i_passport.initialize();

const api = {
   login: async (req, res) => {
      // simulate express body-parser
      const query = {};
      i_url.parse(req.url).query.split('&').forEach((kv) => {
         const parts = kv.split('=');
         const k = decodeURIComponent(parts[0]);
         const v = decodeURIComponent(parts[1] || '');
         query[k] = v;
      });
      req.query = query;
      const cookie = {};
      req.headers.cookie.split('; ').forEach((kv) => {
         const parts = kv.trim().split('=');
         const k = decodeURIComponent(parts[0]);
         const v = decodeURIComponent(parts[1] || '');
         query[k] = v;
      });
      req.cookies = cookie;

      i_passport.authenticate('oauth2', (err, user, info) => {
         try {
            if (err) return makeRedirect(res, '/login.html?error=400');
            if (!user) return makeRedirect(res, '/login.html?error=401');
            // TODO: the user logged in. res.end(user.username);
         } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
         }
         return makeRedirect(res, '/login.html?error=500');
      })(req, res);
   }
};
```